# google speech to text generate session based auth token for client

Tags: google-oauth, speech-to-text

I am building a speech to text application for browser. Right now I am recording and sending the voice from frontend to backend, from backend calling the google api for converstion. Now the problem is processing time is high.

what I need is to call the google api from frontend itself. problem with this step is api key is getting exposed to user and leads to security issue.

So can I generate a session based auth token for speech to text api, which will be valid for client for some duration of time. any tutorial link will also do.

Answer (score 0):

Just about everything Google creates supports OAuth 2.0. Text to Speech certainly does.

Authenticating is easy. Here is a link on how to use OAuth 2.0 with Google APIs.

[Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)

Here is link on how to integrate Google Sign-In to your Web App:

[Add Google Sign-In to Your Web App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/)

And a link for adding OAuth 2 to your backend server in PHP:

[Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app)

I would use [Google Accounts](https://account.google.com/) to start. Google Sign-In makes this easy to implement for the client. Either implement OAuth 2.0 on the backend (recommended) or on the client.

Once you complete the OAuth 2 flow, you will have a `token` that consists of an `Access Token`, `Refresh Token` and `Client ID Token`. You will use the `Access Token` to authorize API calls. You will use the `Refresh Token` to refresh the `Access Token` as it expires every 60 minutes. The `Client ID Token` will provide you with their identity information.